# Appium couldn't identify the locators

Tags: appium

Now I'm in stuck, because identify the locators  I want to click on the google map info window . I tried to do linktext but the linktext not working as expected. it shows an error like

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"XYZ"}


<div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nodecoration" alt="132">XYZ</a></div>
```

the 'XYZ' is an info window title on google map

```
waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'map\']/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/a")));

        MobileElement element5 =(MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'map\']/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/a"));

        waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("XYZ")));


        MobileElement element6 =  element5.findElement(By.linkText("XYZ"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate the parent element of the Element you want to locate and click.
Then try to find the desired element with the help of parent element:

```
WebElement desiredElm = parentElm.findelement(By.linkText("XYZ")).Click();
```

Or use actions:

```
Actions action3 = new Actions(Setup.driver);
action3.MoveToElement(element6).Perform();
Thread.Sleep(4000);
action3.Click( element6).Perform();
```

Comment: I tried to put the above code, but still got the error. Can you see my question i edied

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to locate a non-hyperlink element  element using **linkText**. Try locating the element using the code below -

```
 waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.Xpath(//div[@title ='General Hospital Ernakulam')));
```

Note: **linkText** and **partialLinktext** work only for elements with HTML tag "a".

Comment: Actually there is a anchor tag inside that div..

Comment: You can identify that element with linkText. But does the link text for that element is 'General Hospital Ernakulam'?

Comment: If you could paste a screenshot of the anchor tag, I might be able to help you.

Comment: Please see the edited question..

Comment: Try -waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.Xpath("//div[@title ='General Hospital Ernakulam']/a"))